# Can't embed bash command in to Chef Recipe

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I'm attempting to embed a shell command in to my Chef Recipe, however when Chef executes the command it seems to get things wrong.  Here's the resource in question:

```
script "create libs symlink" do
  interpreter "bash"
  user "root"
  cwd "/home/robin/test"
  code <<-EOH
ln -s $(ls -1 | grep '^[0-9.-]\+$') curr-version-libs
  EOH
end
```

The `/home/robin/test` directory contains a folder called 19.26-3, so I'm expecting a symlink called `curr-version-libs` pointing at `19.26-3`.

Instead, I'm ending up with a circular symlink:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Jan 17 22:35 19.26-3
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jan 17 22:35 config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    17 Jan 28 17:31 curr-version-libs -> curr-version-libs
```

It seems that the $(ls -1 | grep '^[0-9.-]+$') is being removed and I'm ending up with the command `ln -s curr-version-libs`.

Does anyone know what's going on here?  I've tried using an `execute` resource, but I get the same results.

Comment: The expansion will effectively be removed if `grep` doesn't match anything at the time the command is run. Are you sure the directory exists at that time, and isn't being created later by another chef recipe? You can do `ls -l > ls_snapshot` and then check ls_snapshot to see which files are there at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your **19.26-3** directory exists before chef run starts, then it is easy. If you are creating a symbolic link, I would recommend using **link** resource for that.

```
version = `ls /home/robin/test/ -1 | grep '^[0-9.-]+$'`.strip

link "/home/robin/test/curr-version-libs" do
  to ::File.join( "/home/robin/test", version )
end
```

But if it is not there, I would recommend using ruby_block and defining your link resource dynamically.

```
ruby_block "create libs symlink" do
  block do
    version = `ls /home/robin/test/ -1 | grep '^[0-9.-]+$'`.strip
    res = Chef::Resource::Link.new( "/home/robin/test/curr-version-libs", run_context )
    res.to ::File.join( "/home/robin/test", version )
    res.run_action :create
  end
end
```

**Edit:** I corrected the answer by fixing regex and and calling *strip* before assigning to version as Robin proposed.

Comment: That looks like it'll work - I'll give it a go tomorrow and let you now how I get on.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, your second suggestion turned out to be the winner - the first one executed in the wrong order.  Also, I had to remove the backslash from the regex, and I had to do `version = version.delete("\n")` to strip trailing rubbish from the link name.  Thanks again!

Comment: Why would you only recommend using the using the *link* resource for a symbolic link? Also, all of the command line operations performed in your code could be performed much more easily and in a portable fashion using Ruby Core or Standard Library classes.

Comment: I never said that I recommend it only for symbolic links. It is the way to create any link, and even on windows nodes. Concerning the command line operations, that could be performed using Ruby. I am not that good at ruby, and just copied the OP code. I guess you could elaborate on that and provide your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are calling out to the shell to create a sym link. In that case, a much better way to do this is to use the [Chef link resource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_link.html). I would never use the *script* or *execute* resource to do what you are doing.

Using the link resource, you would do the following:

```
  link "/home/robin/test/curr-version-libs" do
    to '/home/robin/test/19.26-3'
    user 'root'
    group 'root'
    link_type :symbolic 
    action :create
  end
```

A quick side commentary: I have mentored and tutored a number of folks to come up on Chef. Those who come to understand what is offered by the resources, providers, and lightweight resources (aka. LWRPs) are much happier and effective than those who just try to drop their old shell scripts into their cookbooks.

I highly recommend reading the [Resource and Providers](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/resources.html) and [Lightweight Resources](http://docs.opscode.com/chef/lwrps.html) Documentation

Answer (score 0):

have you tried escaping dollar sign?

```
ln -s \$(ls -1 | grep '^[0-9.-]\+$') curr-version-libs
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried escaping both of them and it makes no difference.  I've also tried using backticks, and again, same thing